# Pass variable from child window to parent window between 2 applications

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, showmodaldialog, window.parent

I have opened a child window using a `showModal` dialog where the URL points to a different website as the main window does.

I want to pass some variables from the child window to the parent window using the script below.

Script used in Parent window:

```
function Open() {
    var Return;
    Return = window.showModalDialog("https://example.com/ChildApp/ChildForm.aspx", "", "dialogWidth:670px;dialogHeight:600px;")
    alert(Return.passVariable);
}
```

The URL for the parent window is something like this: https://example.com/MainApp/MainForm.aspx

Script used in Child window:

```
function Close(parameter) {
    var vReturnValue = new Object();
    vReturnValue.passVariable= parameter;
    window.returnValue = vReturnValue;
    window.close();
}
```

In the main window, `Return` returns `null`.

One more issue exists when I'm trying to get a reference of `window.parent`, it gives a `null` value in the child window.

Note: Here ChildApp and MainApp are two different applications.

Comment: Is it a windows store app?

Comment: By "two different applications", you imply that they are on different domains? Your `example` urls should make that clear.

Comment: [Don't use `showModalDialog`](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/05/02/showmodaldialog-what-it-is-and-why-you-should-never-use-it/). There are better solutions, and cross-domain messaging will solve your problem.

Comment: @Bergi yes I mean they are on different domains,

I am using IE8

Comment: @Salketer no it is not a window store app

Comment: @vijayp: Is the page supposed to be usable only in IE8? I'm so sorry.

Comment: @Bergi, Nope, I was suppose to mention this in my question, yes the application is very old works only up to IE9 and in IE10 and IE11 with Compatability mode On.